# appending erased file has too much disturbed noice

Tags: objective-c, audio, nsmutabledata

I am erasing audio file using following code:

NSMutableData *wave =[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.recordedFileURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];

```
NSUInteger length = [wave length];

Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(length);
memcpy(byteData, [wave bytes], length);
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:byteData length:length];

[data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(length*rangeToCut, length-(length*rangeToCut)) withBytes:NULL length:0];

[data writeToFile:[self.recordedFileURL path] atomically:YES];
```

it is erasing correctly but after that when i resume my audio ad append resumed part to old part like following:

NSMutableData *part2=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.soundFileURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];

```
         NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingToURL:oldURL error:nil];
         if (file) {

         [file seekToEndOfFile];
         [file writeData:part2];
         }
```

then audio files are appended successfully but resumed part of audio has too much disturbance not able to listen that part.

Please help me what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Is your sample size 16 bits or more? If you cut the audio in the middle of a sample the rest of the stream will be just noise. You need to be sure of length*rangeToCut being a multiple of the sample size.